# Different monitor connectors

Tags: dvi, vga, mini-displayport, mini-dvi

Does anybody know of a good Web site or so that explains the differences between current monitor connectors and which screen uses which connector?

Comment: Jeff Atwood today wrote a blog entry that answers some of my question:

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/three-monitors-for-every-user.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_video_connectors) might be a good source to start ([DVI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface), [VGA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_Graphics_Array), [HDMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-Definition_Multimedia_Interface)). Also, the `which screen uses which connector` is a little bit like asking `which car uses which wheel format`, I don't think that there is whole database for that.

Comment: I have an Apple Cinema Display and no idea what all those different connectors are.

Comment: @Andrew J. Brehm: Well, why didn't you ask/say that in the first place? So you wanna know who to connect it or what different connectors it has (RTM maybe)?

Comment: I am looking for a general list of all current connector types.

Comment: @Andrew J. Behm: You mean for connectors between a PC and a Monitor? VGA, DVI, HDMI...there you go. ;) But for the 'exotics' please see my Wikipedia-Link.